# preg_match_all text between alteration strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I would need to get the text between certain strings with preg_match_all. I've tried using alternation, but I'm not getting the right info out. What I need is to get the randomtext between weekday-strings. From Friday it should go to the end of the text.

My data is as follows:

```
Monday 1.1.
randomtext
randomtext
Tuesday 2.1.
randomtext
randomtext
Wednesday 3.1
randomtext
randomtext
Thusday 4.1.
randomtext
randomtext
randomtext
Friday 5.1
randomtext
randomtext
```

What I have now is this, but it only captures the stuff after Monday, when it should stop to Tuesday and then do it again:

```
/(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday)([\s\S]+)/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_split()`.

```
$day_pattern = '/([a-z]+?day [\d\.]+\n)/i';
$bits = preg_split(
    $day_pattern,
    $str,
    null,
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
);
if ($bits)
    foreach($bits as $bit)
        echo preg_match($day_pattern, $bit)
            ?
            '<h3>'.$bit.'</h3>'
            :
            '<p>'.$bit.'</p>';
```

Outputs

```
<h3>Monday 1.1.</h3>
<p>randomtext
randomtext</p>
<h3>Tuesday 2.1.</h3>
<p>randomtext
randomtext</p>
<h3>Wednesday 3.1</h3>
<p>randomtext
randomtext</p>
<h3>Thusday 4.1.</h3>
<p>randomtext
randomtext
randomtext</p>
<h3>Friday 5.1</h3>
<p>randomtext
randomtext</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,use `m` modifier and `^`+`$` to match each line of your text.

```
$datas = <<<data
Monday 1.1.
randomtext
randomtext
Tuesday 2.1.
randomtext
randomtext
Wednesday 3.1
randomtext
randomtext
Thusday 4.1.
randomtext
randomtext
randomtext
Friday 5.1
randomtext
randomtext
data;
preg_match_all('#^(?!Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thusday|Friday)\w+$#im',$datas,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example actually the 'Random text....' is not between certain string as it lacks the string at the end, ie after Friday

```
Monday 1.1.
randomtext1
randomtext2
Tuesday 2.1.
randomtext3
randomtext4
Wednesday 3.1
randomtext5
randomtext6
Thursday 4.1.
randomtext7
randomtext8
randomtext9
Friday 5.1
randomtext10
randomtext11
Monday
```

If the text will be like above, ie it will be between Weekday string always, you can use the following pattern.

```
 (?<=Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday)([\s\S]+?)(?=Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday)
```